# How is Modulo used/defined under the sequence number function? Sequence Number Function and Hilbert's tenth problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to understand Hilbert's tenth problem and some of the proofs which show it is unsolvable. To date I've been using this [paper](https://carleton.ca/math/wp-content/uploads/Brandon-Savage-Barnhart-honours-project.pdf) and Hilbert’s Tenth Problem An Introduction  to Logic, Number Theory, and Computability by M. Ram Murty and Brandon Fodden as a guide.

The specific issue I'm having is with the examples shown for (, )  at the bottom of page 7 of [1](https://carleton.ca/math/wp-content/uploads/Brandon-Savage-Barnhart-honours-project.pdf).

In both texts they use a function involving modulo. In both texts it is important that this function equals a natural number. However in cases where x (mod y) = 0 this would seem to lead to a contradiction. In these cases the texts simply state x (mod y) = y.  Can someone explain to me why  x (mod y) = y and not 0? An example of this is the case of 6 mod 2 in the

[Screenshot of text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6eWK.png)

Comment: BTW. There was a thorough exposition of Hilbert's 10th in Amer. Math. Monthly, circa 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of the function $S(i,u)$ its value is in the range $[1,1+iR(u)]$. That is,
$$1\leq S(i,u)\leq 1+iR(u),$$
holds by definition. Note that for any integer $y$ we have
$$y\equiv0\pmod{y},$$
so if $x\equiv 0\pmod{y}$ then also $x\equiv y\pmod{y}$. For the function $S(i,u)$ we simply choose a representative in the range $[1,1+iR(u)]$ for the remainder mod $1+iR(u)$.

For the example you link, computing $S(i,16)$ we see that $L(16)=6$ and $R(16)=1$, so $S(i,16)$ is the unique natural number $w$ satisfying:
$$w\equiv6\pmod{1+i}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad1\leq w\leq1+i.$$
For $i=1$ this becomes $w\equiv6\pmod{2}$ and $1\leq w\leq2$. Clearly $6\equiv2\pmod{2}$ so $S(1,16)=2$.

For $i=2$ this becomes $w\equiv6\pmod{3}$ and $1\leq w\leq3$. Clearly $6\equiv3\pmod{3}$, so $S(2,16)=3$.

For $i=3$ this becomes $w\equiv6\pmod{4}$ and $1\leq w\leq4$. Clearly $6\equiv2\pmod{4}$ so $S(3,16)=2$.

Etcetera.